# Register and deregister an event with reflection in WinRT

Tags: c#, .net, events, windows-runtime

For my open source project http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com I am trying to implement an improved page class for WinRT and WinPRT (8.1). The class is located in a PCL library. This is why I have to register the back pressed event by reflection. The code without reflection looks like this:

```
using Windows.Phone.UI.Input;

namespace SampleUniversalPhoneApp
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public void Start()
        {
            HardwareButtons.BackPressed += OnBackPressed;
        }

    public void Stop()
    {
        HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= OnBackPressed;
    }

    private void OnBackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Add more code
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

}

Now I need the exact same logic but with reflection because the `HardwareButtons` and the `BackPressedEventArgs` classes are not available in my PCL library.

How can I do that?

Comment: The point of PCL not exposing classes is to *help* you avoid taking a dependency on a class that's not supported by one of the targets you selected.  Using reflection to work around that completely misses the point: it will of course just fail on a target that doesn't support the class.  PCL wasn't made to make your life more difficult, it was made to keep you out of trouble.  If you like trouble then don't use PCL.

Comment: I use this to implement a new page base class which can be used in universal wp and winrt apps. When used in wp the backpressed event is used, when used in winrt the back key (delete) up event is used. This has to be in the pcl library so that page implementations for both devices can also be in a pcl...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution for this question:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private object _backPressedToken;
    private static readonly Type _hardwareButtonsType;
    private static readonly EventInfo _backPressedEvent;

    static MyClass()
    {
        _hardwareButtonsType = Type.GetType(
            "Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons, " +
            "Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, " +
            "PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime");

        if (_hardwareButtonsType != null)
            _backPressedEvent = _hardwareButtonsType.GetRuntimeEvent("BackPressed");
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        // Register event
        Action<object, object> callback = OnBackKeyPressed;
        var callbackMethodInfo = callback.GetMethodInfo();
        var backPressedDelegate = callbackMethodInfo.CreateDelegate(_backPressedEvent.EventHandlerType, this);
        _backPressedToken = _backPressedEvent.AddMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { backPressedDelegate });
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        // Unregister event
        _backPressedEvent.RemoveMethod.Invoke(null, new [] { _backPressedToken });
        _backPressedToken = null; 
    }

    private void OnBackKeyPressed(object sender, dynamic args)
    {
        // Handle event
        if (!args.Handled)
            args.Handled = DoIt(args.Handled);
    }
}
```

Finally used in this class:

https://github.com/MyToolkit/MyToolkit/blob/master/src/MyToolkit.Extended/Paging/Handlers/BackKeyPressedHandler.cs

Answer (score 0):

A PCL Library is intended to be used with either a Phone, tablet or computer application, that's why you won't find any UI specific classes.

So that will be the job of your library's client to manage those UI specific mechanisms.

I don't think it's a good idea to use reflection; if you start using it, you'll end up with a library full of reflection code, hard to maintain, hard to understand.

IMHO, you should change your architecture, giving more power to the library's client.

As a side note, Microsoft will soon release a new VS2013 update (already available as beta), allowing you to develop an unique application for all Microsoft based devices.

Comment: This is already a W8.1 and WP8.1 PCL library which can share everything except this particular API. This is why I have to register the event by reflection... DI is my current solution but I don't like it for this particular problem... I need to do this by reflection to have a nice design..

Comment: BTW: Libraries targeting wp8.1 and w8.1 are still PCL targeting only these two platform and therefore allowing access to almost everything (except HardwareButtons..)

Comment: Are the 2 CreateDelegate methods unavailable ? [Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53cz7sc6(v=vs.110).aspx) and [MethodInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/hh194376(v=vs.110).aspx)